# How much power loss does the LLCD suffer in transit?

Tags: the-moon, artificial-satellite, communication, ladee, laser

[Space.com](http://www.space.com/22680-nasa-lunar-laser-communications-experiment-infographic.html) writes to say (freeform improved quote):

> The [LLCD](http://esc.gsfc.nasa.gov/267/271.html) (Lunar Laser Communication Demonstration) space terminal is designed to beam data from the moon at a rate six times faster than the best advanced radio communications systems available today. The system consists of a laser mount on the [LADEE](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/ladee/main/index.html) (Lunar Atmosphere and Dust Environment Explorer) spacecraft which fires a 0.5-watt laser through a **10-centimeter telescope...** The primary ground station, called the Lunar Lasercom Ground Terminal, is located in White Sands, New Mexico, near Las Cruces and features a set of **four 40-centimeter telescopes** to receive the signal.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_fiber) indicates 4 db/km attenuation in optical fibres was achieved decades ago. In free space, the attenuation would be higher; which brings me to my questions:

- How much power does the LLCD lose in transit from Lunar orbit to the ground station?
- Could the gas in the laser module freeze when in space?

Comment: Why would the loss be higher in free space than optical fibers?

Answer (score 7):

Pulling some info from the [Fact Sheet](http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/llcdfactsheet.final_.web_.pdf) and [this website](http://www.lexellaser.com/techinfo_wavelengths.htm). The formula, from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_beam#Beam_width_or_spot_size), is

$\theta \simeq \frac{\lambda}{\pi w_0} \qquad (\theta \mathrm{\ in\ radians}). $

I'm going to assume $W_0$ is the aperture width provided. That gives a beam width, assuming 1.1 um wavelength, of about 3.5 uRads

Okay, at that value at the distance of the Earth will give a spot size of about 2.5 km, or an area of 4,900,000 m^2. The total aperture on Earth is about 0.5 m^2. The difference between them gives a maximum path loss of 70 dB. There will be some atmospheric path loss as well, and no doubt the system isn't quite this ideal, but I would expect the total path loss to be around 70-80 dB.