# Long range laser communication beam divergence angle values?

Tags: communication, probe, optical-communication

NASA has been working on [demonstrations of laser communication with satellites](http://www.space.com/22680-nasa-lunar-laser-communications-experiment-infographic.html).  The motivation is simple, in that lasers see less power loss because they spread over a smaller angle.  That raises the question, what *is* the angle over which they spread?

Going by [laser physics fundamentals](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13648/physics-of-focusing-a-laser), it seems that for our purposes any Gaussian beam can be effectively taken to be waist-less.  By that I mean, the area of the beam at the target distance will be *literally* the [solid angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle) time the distance.

[image: laser spread with waist]

There is some information on the [Lunar Lasercom Ground Terminal (LLGT)](http://web.archive.org/web/20130215161346/http://esc.gsfc.nasa.gov/267/271/Ground-Terminal.html) (archived page, link isn't working due to govt shutdown?), but none of these specs relate to the divergence angle.  Laser pointers you can buy in stores can be [1-3 mrad](http://laserpointerforums.com/f49/typical-beam-divergence-rates-59627.html), which sounds small, but it's really not.  Such a beam is literally half the diameter of the moon.  A tighter beam introduces a tradeoff where it gets harder to aim, but preserves more of the beam intensity.  I'm interested to know where, along that spectrum, modern space laser communications fall.

Comment: Don't know the answer, but I recall hearing that the lasers bounced off the mirrors on the moon typically form an illuminated area 'the size of a football field'.  I guess that was extrapolated from the distance and the laser specs., since I doubt any Earth based detector would be sensitive enough to 'see' the lit area beyond the mirror itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From @PearsonArtPhoto's answer [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/2006/29), he estimates a beamwidth of about **$3.5~\text{$\mu$rad}$**, or roughly $0.002~\text{deg}$ (unfortunately, his [main source](http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/llcdfactsheet.final_.web_.pdf) is also offline because of the government shutdown). He goes on to point out that this corresponds to an area on the Earth of about $4.9~\text{km}^2$.

While this does indeed levy a tighter pointing requirement, it's still about 10 times larger than typical absolute pointing accuracy seen in [ground-based telescopes](http://books.google.com/books?id=PBN5XZjagbsC&lpg=PA253&ots=M_6oIyK6Qr&dq=ground%20telescope%20pointing%20accuracy&pg=PA253#v=onepage&q=ground%20telescope%20pointing%20accuracy&f=false) (about 1 arcsec).

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe I didn't see that question.  It is extremely similar to what I asked here.